# User directory in PATH in zsh: ~ Does Not Work

Tags: macos, path, zsh

I'm doing this in my .zshrc

```
   PATH="~/scripts:$PATH"
```

and if I do `echo $PATH` it appears as the first thing in the path. Yet this directory isn't included in the executable path (nor for tab-completion). **What am I doing wrong?** `ls ~/scripts` shows the directory as expected.

**Edit:** This works, though... I guess `~` doesn't work in the path?

```
#PATH="~/scripts:$PATH"
PATH="/Users/yar/scripts:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 16):

Use `$HOME` instead.

```
PATH="$HOME/scripts:$PATH"
```

Comment: Expansion of `~` in PATH is an abhorrent bashism. The PATH-searching library functions `execlp` or `execvp` do not expand `~`, so other programs that use them to find and run programs in the PATH would also fail to search `~` entries.

Comment: I consider `~` to be a command-line convenience. It shouldn't be used in scripts and variable values for expansion.

Comment: @Chris Johnsen, it's amazing, the main impact on my *nix knowledge after switching shells is learning what is universal and what is not. I think zsh is cool, but I've learned quite a bit suffering through the switch (and I'm only two days in). @Dennis Williamson, I'm getting that, and it makes sense, somehow.